# One IP address?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, postfix

1:- i have one AMIs

2:- with one IP address

3:- i have config postix mail server

4:- apache web server

5:- DNS (bind)

my question (may be very elementary sorry for my english) if you only one ip address for all these what can be issues may i get, on really time and because client is asking for such think

Comment: Whats wrong with 1 ip address if its not a ton of network traffic? Everything goes to different ports it should be fine.

Comment: Seems like you are using Amazon EC2. In this case better use an elastic IP address. Otherwise on restart your IP will change and you get into a trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In very small environments I commonly run DNS, Apache, a mail daemon, and possibly more all on the same server. It's not the best idea, but frequently you have to make do with what you have. As long as the services don't run on the same port, you shouldn't run into any issues (except that a hacker compromising one service gets access to all the rest).

Comment: Agreed.  The only problem with the "one IP in AWS" thing is when you want to set up a TCP load balancer and run multiple VIPs on the same port - that's not possible.  But for normal stuff like the above, it'll work.

Comment: As you said hacker compromising one services gets assess to all the rest will go down!! that was win point for me ay clients place thanks a ton